# what is packaged_resources?

Tags: android, visual-studio, xamarin, computer-science

I am new to Xamarin for visual studio , when I tried to build the auto generated app from visual studio 2015 without any editing it just did not build and those errors occurred :

*Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State Error The file "obj\Debug\android\bin\packaged_resources" does not exist. App1

*Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error "aapt.exe" exited with code -1073741819. App1

I tried many solutions from those who had the same problem but I can't seem to find any solution that actally works for me.

Comment: Check the Android SDK version number and make sure it's the latest. Also double check Xamarin version number.

Comment: @KalaJ thanks for your answer , but my problem was that there is some packages that needs to be deleted

Answer (score 3):

One additional detail that is not mentioned but might be a part of the problem is that the resource files can only contain 'a'-'Z', '0'-'9' and '_' characters. A single resource file can ruin the whole build, which is exactly what happened to me. I suggest to anyone running into this mistake to double check the file names of resources.

Answer (score 0):

Same problem with me. It seems it´s a bug.
Lots of posts out there:
https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/65862/i-cant-build-any-android-project

At this one I´ve seen a light and worked for me:
https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=39910

In short:

- Close VS
- DEL your folder C:\users\\appdata\local\xamarin
- DEL your project sub-folders BIN and OBJ at Droid and IOS
- Use Nuget to update your projects packages
- Update Android Studio SDK if neccessary
- Reopen VS and rebuild your solution.

I hope you have same luck... It was really annoying...
Please let us know. Bye.

Answer (score 0):

Ran into the same problem. After toiling on it for a while, I finally found a viable solution. Apparently, this is like caused by a bug in Android Build Tools 24.0.0. And removing those from the system should solve the problem. A bug has been reported, you can find more details on the link below:

https://releases.xamarin.com/technical-bulletin-android-sdk-build-tools-24/

Answer (score 0):

Installing an older "Android SDK build tools" Version was the solution for me.

- Start the SDK Manager (in VS 15):
   Tools -> Android -> Android SDK Manager ..
- Install "Android SDK Build-tools" version 23.0.1
- Uninstall all other "Android SDK Build-tools" versions
- Build -> rebuild the project / workspace
  (Even safer: run a clean, restart VS, run build)

This was successful with:
Android SDK Tools 25.2.3
Android SDK Platform Tools 25.0.1
Android SDK build tools version 23.0.1

If that works, you can test newer build tools.